# Deferred chaining - then called success callback when previous call finished with error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dojo, deferred

I have a small dialog which should validate before close, get values from inputs and then call the callback given by dialog caller. I've realized processing inputs as function taking callback arguments, so every method in chain is asynchrone.

What I want, is to call isValid, on success callback call getValues, on success callback call okCallback. Here is my code:

```
var self = this
this.isValid().then(lang.hitch(this, this.getValues), function(){
  console.log('Object invalid')
  return false
}).then(function(item) {
   self.okCallback(item)
})
```

The problem is, that the final then() with calling okCallback is called even if isValid() finished with error, adn getValues() were not called.

Is it normal behaviour? How to make deferred chaing, so that final success callback will be called only, if everything before succeeded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is normal behavior. You did already handle the error in

```
function(){
  console.log('Object invalid')
  return false
})
```

from where you did return a non-error value (`false`). To continue with an error, throw another one, throw the same one, or don't use the second argument to `then` but a separate `addErrback`. Or put the error handler after the `.then(lang.hitch(this, this.okCallback))` so it will handle errors from `getValues` as well without affecting the `okCallback`.

Comment: I should 'throw' an error, or return deferrable and call 'reject'?

Comment: I guess you should return a rejected Promise, only [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)-based implementations seem to support real `throw`ing from the handlers.

Comment: Is there any shortcut for returning rejected promise? Creating Deferred, rejecting and returning is 3-liner...

Comment: @ŁukaszL.: From [the docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.9/dojo/Deferred#reject) it looks as if you could use chaining, i.e. `return new Deferred().reject(reason);`